# How to set supported localization programmatically

Tags: ios, localization

When using nib files I can set the supported localizations here:

[image]

When this is done and the pop up "Paste" button will be translated into the system language like this:[image][image]

But I'm not using a nib file now, and the translate will not happen, so how can I programmatically set the supported localizations just like what I did to the nib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a nib file, I am guessing you are creating the `UIView`'s in the code. I would just use the `NSLocalizedString(string,comment)` function and would assign it's translation on the moment of the `UIView`'s creation.

Comment: Seems that if I add an Localizable.strings the translate will work. Thank you for leading me to this solution.